# Spring Boot application is ignoring java config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a fairly simple Spring Boot app I am working on that uses a few Java Config classes.  However, it seems that the configuration is not being picked up.  I have break points all over, but nothing gets tripped.  I even tossed a few `RuntimeException`s just to see if maybe my debugger was on the fritz.

In my main class, I have the standard Spring Boot main:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tagged it with `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.  The `Application` class lives at the root of the classpath.  My understanding of the `@ComponentScan` annotation is that it will search for all configuration classes beneath it.

In a package one layer down I have all the config classes:

My "Common" configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.codechimp.XXX.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppCommonConfig {
    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    /* Define common beans here like datasource and such */
}
```

And my Spring Security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Inject
    private LocalXXXUserDetailsService localXXXUserDetailsService;

        /**
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //  Configure http
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)
     */
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        // Configure auth
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app, it doesn't seem to call any of the methods in either of these config classes.  It's as if they are being completely ignored.  As I said, I have tried setting break points and even throwing a RuntimeException right in the beginning of all the methods like so:

```
if (true)
    throw new RuntimeException("Break!");
```

Admittedly I have not had much experience with using Java Config, but I have been over the docs again and again and I am not seeing the missing piece(s).

Comment: Any luck with the issue?. I am too facing the same issue. I can't seem understand why the configuration is being picked up. Only few configs are pickedup and few are not. In my case I have multiple WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

I think you need your `Application` to be a `@Configuration`.

It's not a great idea to do a `@ComponentScan` from the default package (I assume that's what you mean by "the root of the classpath"). That would definitely switch some things off, but more seriously it causes a huge scan of all jars on your classpath, which is not a great idea (and can cause the app to fail).

Comment: By "root" I mean the common root of my application's classpath, for example com.xxx.yyy, with all my code classes sorted into sub-packages like "domain", "config", etc.  I agree that scanning from "default" would be bad, not to mention a horrible way to organize your code.  I will try adding `@Configuration` to my `Application` class and report back.

Comment: I just tried adding the `@Configuration` to `Application`, but it still does not seem to be loading the config classes.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Nope. Can you post the whole project somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

to your Spring Boot main class. From the docs:

> /**
>    * Indicates a {@link Configuration configuration} class that declares one or more
>    * {@link Bean @Bean} methods and also triggers {@link EnableAutoConfiguration
>    * auto-configuration} and {@link ComponentScan component scanning}. This is a convenience
>    * annotation that is equivalent to declaring {@code @Configuration},
>    * {@code @EnableAutoConfiguration} and {@code @ComponentScan}.
>    *
>    * @author Phillip Webb
>    * @author Stephane Nicoll
>    * @since 1.2.0
>    */